# Cannot open share when user name contains @

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-files

My user name for an SMB share contains an @ (like hans@blah.com). It works fine from the terminal masking it with a \ (like hans\@blah.com). This, however, does not work from pantheon-files. Looking into the log at the target, I can see that the user arrives as hans only. If I mask it or not, the log on attempt is always with the name part only.

Any solution for this?